# I want to print out the enumerator data in columns or as a list

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, constructor, enumerator

SO...I have this piece of code here.

```
    class secondary
{
    enum DocDetails
    {
        DrHowlett(500, "Orthopedist"),
        DrMurdock(300, "ENT specialist"),
        DrNarendra(1000, "Nephrologist"),
        DrWhite(10000, "Pulmonologist"),
        DrSummers(1500, "Opthalmologist"),
        DrStark(12000, "Cardiologist"),
        DrBanner(20000, "Radiologist");

    private int x;
    private String z;
    private DocDetails(int y, String a)
    {

        x=y;
        z=a;
    }

}
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        for(DocDetails d:DocDetails.values())
        {
            System.out.println(d);
            System.out.println(d.x);
            System.out.println(d.z);
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to print out like this

```
DrHowlett 500 Ortopedist
DrMurdock 300 ENT specialist
....and so on.
```

But this is the actual output of the code

```
DrHowlett
500
Orthopedist
DrMurdock
300
ENT specialist
DrNarendra
1000
Nephrologist
DrWhite
10000
Pulmonologist
DrSummers
1500
Opthalmologist
DrStark
12000
Cardiologist
DrBanner
20000
Radiologist
```

Everything is printed in the next line. 
I have a project where I have to store details in an enumerator and print them out. And it would not be useful if I just print them out in a long meaningless list. I want to have the attributes side by side instead of everything being printed in the next line.

Comment: Try [String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) you can read about various formatting options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use System.out.print() fort he first 2 print statements. Keep the last one as System.out.println();

Also add spaces to the end of the first 2 println statements.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    for(DocDetails d:DocDetails.values())
    {
        System.out.print(d + " ");
        System.out.print(d.x + " ");
        System.out.println(d.z);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're using "println" (i.e. print line) which will always include a newline at the end of each call. You could use System.out.print (which doesn't include the new line) but it is cleaner if you use String.format:

```
System.out.println("%s\t%d\t%s".format(d, d.x, dz));
```

That will write a line with each field separated by a tab.